# Insertar Imagen en cuerpo de correo con C# y Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

Tags: c#

Busco ayuda por si alguien podría ayudarme. Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda.

Estoy intentando enviar un correo con C# y Outlook usando la librería propia que viene en Visual Studio (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook)

El problema es que no consigo adjuntar una imagen local, guardada en una carpeta, en el cuerpo del correo.

He buscado en muchos sitios, pero no encuentro una solución que use la librería Interop.Outlook (es obligatorio usar esta librería, pues es para el trabajo y no puedo usar otra que no sea esa para enviar el correo).

Les adjunto el código:

Muchas gracias por su ayuda!!
Un saludo!

Comment: Falta el codigo...

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow. Te invito a leer [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y de paso revisar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para futuras preguntas que realices, además, con ello ganarás tu primera medalla. Agrega el código para que la comunidad pueda apoyarte. Saludos.